# How to access JS for <g > in SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

For action svg need access to the group svg

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg_main" >

<g id="layer1" x="50" y="50"  width="60">

             id="path3047"
             style="fill:#008000" />

</svg>
```

How to reach id="layer1"

```
<div  id="svg">
  <object  id="my_obj" class="svg_ob" type="image/svg+xml" data="./svg/index2.svg"></object>
</div>

var testMapObj = document.getElementById('my_obj').contentDocument;

console.log(testMapObj);

var levelMy = testMapObj.getElementById('level1');
//or 

//$(document).on("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    //var theSvgDocument = document.getElementById("my_obj").getSVGDocument();

    // theSvgElement = theSvgDocument.documentElement;

// });
```

Not working . Why?
How to fix it?(What's the best way to solve this issue?)

Comment: I'm guessing this was a copy-paste error, but you do realize that you have an invalid node, right? `id="path3047 style="fill:#008000" />` does not have a starting-`<` or tag name.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you access to the `<g>` element inside of your `<svg>`:

```
var g = $('svg').children('#layer1');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9aZ3/)

Assuming you've only used that `id` once, you can just do this:

```
var g = $('#layer1');
```